# Next.js router error while testing using React-testing-library

Tags: jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I was just trying to do a preliminary test of rendering a component that is redirecting the user on the basis of the login status and thus using `router` from `next/router` in `componentDidMount` but getting the following error:

> No router instance found.
> You should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.

It appears to me that from *client side* it means using the *router* or *Link* has to be used inside of the render method as that is what makes the DOM and other methods like lifecycle, hooks, and server-side doesn't so in those cases it would throw an error.

I know that testing the entire component beats the purpose of unit testing but I wanted to do this anyway. Therefore, I followed this [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7479) and it appears that the router has to be mocked in order to be used by the *React-Testing-Library* but none of the solutions work for me.

Here is the code that I tried:

```js
describe('Home Page', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', async () => {
    render(<Home />)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 5):

a solution like:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
...
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
    useRouter: jest.fn(),
}))
...
;(useRouter as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => ({
    pathname: '/',
    push: mockPush,
}))
```

will work.

the error you're encountering will be triggered if you do not mock useRouter in the initial mock (i.e.:

```
...
jest.mock('next/router')
...
```

Comment: Amazing! this was annoying the hell out of me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Mocked the *router* using the  `next-router-mock` library. Just pasted `jest.mock('next/router', () => require('next-router-mock'));` before the test and the tests are passing.

```
jest.mock('next/router', () => require('next-router-mock'));
describe('Home Page', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', async () => {
    render(<Home />)
  })
})
```

Although, the test is passing but getting this warning that is not making any sense to me.

```
 › 1 snapshot obsolete.
   • Home Page renders without crashing 1
Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot obsolete from 1 test suite. To remove it, press `u`.
   ↳ tests/homePage.test.js
       • Home Page renders without crashing 1
```

Assuming that there is a better way to mock the router.